# Installation issue with GWT Designer

Tags: eclipse, gwt, windowbuilder, gwt-designer

Environment: Ubuntu 12.04.3 x86_64 with Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler) and Oracle jdk-7u45-linux-x64

I installed GPE and GWT and GWT designer as described in:

http://www.gwtproject.org/download.html

The GWT works fine, I can run the demo client/server application.

However, GWT designer does not seem to be installed.  When I go into File->New->Other->WindowBuilder, I do not see a GWT Designer option, as advertised.  I just see "Project Palette".

I tried other combinations (Eclipse Juno, JDK 1.6, etc), with exactly the same problem.